# Add string item from list B to List<string> within list A

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
class ListA
{ 

   public string A {get; set;}
   public string B {get; set;}
   public List<string> C {get; set;}

}

class ListB
{
   public string A {get; set;}
   public string Z {get; set;} 
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the best way to join the lists. If `ListA` member A is equal to `ListB` member A then the member Z from `ListB` should be added to the `List<String> C` within `ListA`. ListA has a one to many with List B

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything? there are lots of examples in the documentation about how to join collections using LINQ.you can take a look at them as a starting point .

Comment: 101 LINQ SAMPLES - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-linq-samples-3fb9811b

Comment: What means ListA has a one to many with List B

Comment: The instance of the member A within ListA only appears once in the list but many times in ListB, I can join the two lists with             var newList = from a in ListA
                          join b in ListB a.A equals b.A into n select new {A = a.A, B = a.B, C = ??} I'm not sure how to get ListB member Z into the new List<String> C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Join` which is an efficient way to link elements. This creates an `IEnumerable<anonymoustype>` which contains both members.

```
var join = from a in listA
           join b in listB
           on a.A equals b.A
           select new { a, b };

foreach(var both in join)
{
    both.a.C.Add(both.b.Z)
}
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I wanted :)